# Bootstrap CMS system for text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I worked with bootstrap some years now, but are really tired of I do not have any CMS system, where I can write text for a website. At the moment I am writing text in the code, which is not a good solution.

Does anybody know a bootstrap CMS system, where fx you can take a bootstrap template, and just edit the text on the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[T3 Framework](http://www.t3-framework.org) is a Joomla based content management system with inbuilt twitter bootstrap support.